# insert array in multiple rows

Tags: php

I have an array in the following format.

```
{
    "rollArray": "['MSIT/16/001','MSIT/16/006']"
}
```

I want to insert the individual roll numbers in separate columns inside mysql database. Till now I have used the following code in php.

```
$array_length = count($rollArray);

for($x=0; $x<$array_length; $x++)
    {

        $query = "INSERT INTO attendance_count(roll_numbers) VALUES ('$rollArray[$x]')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query))
        {
            echo "successfull";
        }
    }
```

But when I checked the database, I noticed that I am getting only a single starting bracket.

```
[
```

db field screenshot attached.

[image]

Please, help me.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you very much. after I decoded the array once more using json_decode, problem solved. thanks.